# Pyspark : How to take Minimum in the timestamp column?

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark , i tried to do this

```
df = df.select(F.col("id"),
               F.col("mp_code"),
               F.col("mp_def"),
               F.col("mp_desc"),
               F.col("mp_code_desc"),                     
               F.col("zdmtrt06_zstation").alias("station"),                            
               F.to_timestamp(F.col("date_time"), "yyyyMMddHHmmss").alias("date_time_utc"))

df = df.groupBy("id", "mp_code", "mp_def", "mp_desc", "mp_code_desc", "station").min(F.col("date_time_utc"))
```

But, i have an issue

```
raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Comment: Any particular part of it where you're stuck?

Comment: i don't how i combine groub by and order by in ppyspark

Comment: what do you mean by combining group by and order by? You should write your question more specifically. you can also provide an example input and ouput

Comment: the timestamp column is not iterable. 
How can i do for take the min ?

Comment: i think the correct syntax is to use `agg()` in your case -- `.groupBy(<blah blah blah>).agg(F.min('date_time_utc').alias('min_date_time_utc'))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extract of the [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.min.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.min)

> `GroupedData.min(*cols)[source]`
>
> Computes the min value for each numeric column for each group.
>
> New in version 1.3.0.
>
> Parameters: `cols : str`

In other words, the `min` function does not support column arguments. It only works with column names (strings) like this:

```py
df.groupBy("x").min("date_time_utc")
# you can also specify several column names
df.groupBy("x").min("y", "z")
```

Note that if you want to use a column object, you have to use `agg`:

```py
df.groupBy("x").agg(F.min(F.col("date_time_utc")))
```